# I want to convert Vararg Integer to Vararg int?

Tags: java, variadic-functions, variable-length-array

The below code is working fine using Integer values for my variadic method. But I want to use "int" instead of "Integer".

Here is the code:

```
package JavaPracticeShuffler;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;


public class MediumLevelExcercisesA {
    
    Scanner number;
    Scanner yorn;
    
    public MediumLevelExcercisesA(){
        
    }
    
    static void DisplayNumbers(Integer...a) {
        for (int b = 0; b < a.length; b++) {
            System.out.print(a[b]);
            System.out.print(" ");
        }
    }
    
    static void SumOfNumbers(Integer...a) {
        int total = 0;
        for (int b = 0; b < a.length; b++) {
            total += a[b];
        }
        System.out.println(" ");
        System.out.println("Sum: " + total);
    }
    
    
        
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MediumLevelExcercisesA obj01 = new MediumLevelExcercisesA();
        List<Integer> lnumber = new ArrayList<Integer>();
                
        boolean numbercounter = true;
        
        while (numbercounter) {
            obj01.number = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.println("Please input a number");
            int inputnumber = obj01.number.nextInt();
            lnumber.add(inputnumber);
            
            System.out.println("Number/s you've entered so far are the following: " + lnumber);
            
            obj01.yorn = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.println("Do you want to continue?");
            String iyorn = obj01.yorn.nextLine().toUpperCase();
            
            if (iyorn.equals("YES")||iyorn.equals("Y")) {
                System.out.println("You've answered yes, program will proceed.");
            }
            else if (iyorn.equals("NO")||iyorn.equals("N")) {
                System.out.println("You've answered no, program ends.");
                numbercounter = false;
                break;
            }
            else {
                System.out.println("Answer not understood, program continues.");
            }
        } //end of while loop.
        
        System.out.println("Final review of numbers entered: " + lnumber);
        
        Integer[] intarray = new Integer[lnumber.size()];
        intarray = lnumber.toArray(intarray);
        MediumLevelExcercisesA.DisplayNumbers(intarray);
        MediumLevelExcercisesA.SumOfNumbers(intarray);
    }
    
}
```

I want to use "int....variable" instead of "Integer...variable" on my methods. I am assuming that I need to convert variable "intarray" to an int.

Please help I'm stuck on that part, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a int array from your List by utilizing a `for` loop with autoboxing. Then you can change all the method signatures.

```
int[] intarray = new int[lnumber.size()];
for(int i = 0; i < intarray.length; i++)
     intarray[i] = lnumber.get(i);
```

You can also use Streams.

```
int[] intarray = lnumber.stream().mapToInt(Integer::intValue).toArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to do the below steps to changes your program to from Integer to int...

1. Change parameter of `DisplayNumbers(Integer...a)` to `DisplayNumbers(int...a)`
2. Again change parameter of `SumOfNumbers(Integer...a)` to `SumOfNumbers(int...a)`
3. After that, you need to do some code changes in the `main` method. i.e. instead of

   ```
   Integer[] intarray = new Integer[lnumber.size()];
   intarray = lnumber.toArray(intarray);
   ```

you need to write

```
int[] intarray = lnumber.stream().mapToInt(i -> i).toArray();
```

Please find the complete program:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;


public class MediumLevelExcercisesA {

Scanner number;
Scanner yorn;

public MediumLevelExcercisesA(){

}

static void DisplayNumbers(int[] a) {
    for (int b = 0; b < a.length; b++) {
        System.out.print(a[b]);
        System.out.print(" ");
    }
}

static void SumOfNumbers(int...a) {
    int total = 0;
    for (int b = 0; b < a.length; b++) {
        total += a[b];
    }
    System.out.println(" ");
    System.out.println("Sum: " + total);
}



public static void main(String[] args) {
    MediumLevelExcercisesA obj01 = new MediumLevelExcercisesA();
    List<Integer> lnumber = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    boolean numbercounter = true;

    while (numbercounter) {
        obj01.number = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Please input a number");
        int inputnumber = obj01.number.nextInt();
        lnumber.add(inputnumber);

        System.out.println("Number/s you've entered so far are the following: " + lnumber);

        obj01.yorn = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Do you want to continue?");
        String iyorn = obj01.yorn.nextLine().toUpperCase();

        if (iyorn.equals("YES")||iyorn.equals("Y")) {
            System.out.println("You've answered yes, program will proceed.");
        }
        else if (iyorn.equals("NO")||iyorn.equals("N")) {
            System.out.println("You've answered no, program ends.");
            numbercounter = false;
            break;
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("Answer not understood, program continues.");
        }
    } //end of while loop.

    System.out.println("Final review of numbers entered: " + lnumber);

    //Remove below two commented line because it is not need further
    //Integer[] intarray = new Integer[lnumber.size()];
    //intarray = lnumber.toArray(intarray);
    // This can be used for if not java 8 compatible
    /*int[] intarray = new int[lnumber.size()];
    Integer[] temp = lnumber.toArray(new Integer[lnumber.size()]);
    for (int n = 0; n < lnumber.size(); ++n) {
        intarray[n] = temp[n];
    }*/
    //Java 8 and above
    int[] intarray = lnumber.stream().mapToInt(i -> i).toArray();

    MediumLevelExcercisesA.DisplayNumbers(intarray);
    MediumLevelExcercisesA.SumOfNumbers(intarray);
}

}
```